# Generating output based on some date condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this

```
START_DATE      END_DATE      Names

01-FEB-16       03-FEB-16      AAA
01-FEB-16       02-FEB-16      BBB
10-FEB-16       11-FEB-16      CCC
```

If input date is 02-Feb-16. I want to generate all the names if input falls between Start_date and End_date.

(Output should look like)

```
Output(For the problem statement above)

Names 
AAA
BBB
```

Comment: `WHERE input_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date` (assuming proper data types).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi You can use between

e.g.

```
truncate table DROPME_DATES_NAMES;

drop table DROPME_DATES_NAMES;


create table DROPME_DATES_NAMES (date_from date, date_to date, atr_name varchar2(30));

insert into DROPME_DATES_NAMES values (to_date('01-FEB-16','DD-MON-YYYY'), to_date('03-FEB-16','DD-MON-YYYY'), 'AAA ');
insert into DROPME_DATES_NAMES values (to_date('01-FEB-16','DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('02-FEB-16','DD-MON-YYYY'),'BBB');
insert into DROPME_DATES_NAMES values (to_date('10-FEB-16','DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('11-FEB-16','DD-MON-YYYY'),'CCC');


commit;


select atr_name
  from DROPME_DATES_NAMES
where to_date('02-Feb-16','DD-MON-YYYY') between date_from and date_to;
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to use BETWEEN AND to check whether your date falls between one of those pair of dates.

```
WITH your_table AS (
  SELECT TO_DATE('01-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR') start_date, TO_DATE('03-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR') end_date, 'AAA' names FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT TO_DATE('01-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR') start_date, TO_DATE('02-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR') end_date, 'BBB' names FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT TO_DATE('10-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR') start_date, TO_DATE('11-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR') end_date, 'CCC' names FROM DUAL
)  
SELECT names
FROM your_table
WHERE TO_DATE('02-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR') BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```